# Using Sinon and Chai with ES6 constructor

Tags: ecmascript-6, sinon

I'm trying to create unit tests for my class which follows:

MyService.js:

```
const ApiServce = require('./api-service')
const Config = require('./config')
const Redis = require('ioredis')

class MyService {

  constructor () {
    const self = this

    self.apiService = new ApiServce('MyService', '1.0.0', Config.port)

    self.registerRoutes() //this invokes self.apiSerivce.registerRoutes

    self.redis = new Redis(Config.redisport, Config.redishost)
    self.queueKey = Config.redisqueuekey
  }
  run () {
    const self = this
    self.apiService.run()
  }
}

module.exports = MyService
```

Config.js

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.SVC_PORT || 8070,
  redishost: process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  redisport: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  redisqueuekey: process.env.REDIS_Q_KEY || 'myeventqueue'
}
```

Test file:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const MyService = require('../src/myservice')
const ApiService = require('../src/api-service')
const Chai = require('chai')
const Sinon = require('sinon')
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai')

Chai.use(SinonChai)
const should = Chai.should()
const expect = Chai.expect

describe('MyService', function () {
  let apiservicestub, redisstub, apiconststub
  beforeEach(function () {
    apiservicestub = Sinon.stub(ApiService.prototype, 'registerRoutes')
    redisstub = Sinon.stub(Redis.prototype, 'connect')
    redisstub.returns(Promise.resolve())
  })



   describe('.constructor', function () {
     it('creates instances of api service and redis client with correct parameters', Sinon.test(function () {
       try {
        const service = new MyService()
        expect(apiservicestub).called
        expect(redisstub).called
       } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        expect(false)
      }
    }))
```

Questions, Issues:

1. I actually want(ed) to test that the constructors of the dependent classes (apiservice and redis) are being called with the right parameters. But I couldn't find a way so I am currently resorting to one of their methods which is not what I want.

Is there a way in Sinon to achieve this? Do I need to restructure the code to fit Sinon's requirements?

2. I also want to provide test values for Config items e.g. port to see if they get used. Again I couldn't find a way in Sinon to do that.

I tried the createStubInstance for both 1 and 2 as well but keep getting errors.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't use DI and ApiService, etc aren't exported as properties, like exports.ApiService = ApiService, there's no way how you can mock/spy them normally. Use `rewire` or `proxyquire` to take control over `require` calls.

Comment: Ok I will look at those libraries to see how to use those. Would appreciate tips on how to convert the above to use DI etc to allow for normal mocking

Comment: For DI, check any DI library, e.g. `injection-js`, `inversify`, `pioc`. I don't think that this can be explained in a single answer, as it requires some major refactoring. For existing app I would suggest to stick to `rewire` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated test file, thanks @estus for the direction:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const ApiService = require('../src/api-service')
const Chai = require('chai')
const Sinon = require('sinon')
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai')
const Proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
const MyService = require('../src/myservice')

Chai.use(SinonChai)
const should = Chai.should()
const expect = Chai.expect

var namespace = {
  apiServiceStubClass: function () {
  },
  redisStubClass: function () {
  }
}

describe('MyService', function () {
  let ProxiedMyService
  let apiservicestub, redisstub, regroutestub, configstub, apiserviceregroutes, ioredisstub
  beforeEach(function () {
    apiservicestub = Sinon.stub(namespace, 'apiServiceStubClass')
    redisstub = Sinon.stub(namespace, 'redisStubClass')

    configstub = {
      version: 'testversion',
      port: 9999,
      redishost: 'testhost',
      redisport: 9999,
      redisrteventqueuekey: 'testqueyekey'
    }

    ProxiedMyService = Proxyquire('../src/myservice', {
      './api-service': apiservicestub,
      './config': configstub,
      'ioredis': redisstub
    })

    regroutestub = Sinon.stub(ProxiedMyService.prototype, 'registerRoutes')
    regroutestub.returns(true)

    apiserviceregroutes = Sinon.stub(ApiService.prototype, 'registerRoutes')
    regroutestub.returns(true)

    ioredisstub = Sinon.stub(Redis.prototype, 'connect')
    ioredisstub.returns(Promise.resolve())
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    namespace.apiServiceStubClass.restore()
    namespace.redisStubClass.restore()
    ProxiedMyService.prototype.registerRoutes.restore()
    ApiService.prototype.registerRoutes.restore()
    Redis.prototype.connect.restore()
  })

  describe('.constructor', function () {
    it('creates instances of api service and redis client with correct parameters', Sinon.test(function () {
      const service = new ProxiedMyService()
      expect(apiservicestub).to.have.been.calledWithNew
      expect(apiservicestub).to.have.been.calledWith('MyService', 'testversion', 9999)
      expect(regroutestub).to.have.been.called
      expect(redisstub).to.have.been.calledWithNew
      expect(redisstub).to.have.been.calledWith(9999, 'testhost')
      expect(service.queueKey).to.be.equal('testqueyekey')
    }))

    it('creates redis client using host only when port is -1', Sinon.test(function () {
      configstub.redisport = -1
      const service = new ProxiedMyService()
      expect(redisstub).to.have.been.calledWith('testhost')
    }))
  })

  describe('.registerRoutes', function () {
    it('calls apiService registerRoutes with correct url and handler', Sinon.test(function () {
      const service = new MyService()
      expect.....
    }))
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make CommonJS modules testable without additional measures, classes should be exclusively used as properties of `exports` object all through the application. The classes should be destructured from module object in-place. This is not very convenient, but it works with Sinon alone.

I.e.

```
class ApiService {...}
exports.ApiService  = ApiService;

...

const apiServiceModule = require('./api-service');

class MyService {
  constructor () {
    const { ApiService } = apiServiceModule;
    ...
```

In this case the properties on module objects can be mocked before `MyService` instantiation. Sinon spies don't support classes properly, the constructors should be wrapped:

```
sinon.stub(apiServiceModule, 'ApiService', function MockedApiService(...) {
  return new class { constructor (...) ... };
})
```

Alternatively, DI can be used, and the app should be refactored according to that. Existing DI libraries (`injection-js`, `inversify`, `pioc`) can handle this job reasonably, but a simple DI pattern looks like this:

```
class MyService {
  constructor (ApiService, ...) {
    ...
```

In this case all dependencies can be supplied on construction - both in application and in tests.

But most simple way is to use test-oriented packages that mess with module cache and allow to take control over `require` calls (`rewire`, `proxyquire`, `mock-require`).

Comment: Thanks @estus I will try your suggestions